# Using Server Side VB to parse textbox contents from date range

Tags: regex, vb.net, vbscript

I have a date range being inputted into a textbox from a jquery ui daterange selector. I need to get the values on postback of the start date and end date. These values are provided in the textbox, but I'm ignorant on how to seperate out these values on postback with VB server side code. Can anyone show me how I can use vbscript to separate the start and end dates? The textbox results are exactly as follows:

{"start":"2017-04-12","end":"2017-05-17"}

I tried using the following code, but it does not work

```
 Dim strDateStart as String
 Dim strDateEnd as String

 strDateStart = txtSearchDateRange.Text
 strDateStart = Replace(strDateStart, "end*", "")

 strDateEnd = txtSearchDateRange.Text
 strDateEnd = Replace(strDateEnd, "start*", "")
```

Thanks to @Mederic, the following code works:

```
   Dim value As String = txtSearchDateRange.Text
    Dim strStartDate As String = ""
    Dim strEndDate As String = ""

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    ' Call Regex.Matches method.
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(value, "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")

    ' Loop over matches.
    For Each m As Match In matches
        ' Loop over captures.
        For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
            i = i + 1
            ' Display.
            Console.WriteLine("Index={0}, Value={1}", c.Index, c.Value)

            If i = 1 Then strStartDate = c.Value
            If i = 2 Then strEndDate = c.Value

        Next
    Next

    Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>Start Date:" & strStartDate & "<BR><BR>End Date:" & strEndDate)
```

Comment: If starts always comes first then you can use the regex: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` first match will be start second match will be end

Comment: I'm not sure I'm proficient in regex to understand exactly how to do that. Yes, the input will always be provided with start first. Can you insert your RegEx into my code above to show me how it would work with Vb.Net?

Comment: That format looks like json.  I'd use a json parser instead of regex.

Comment: I don't know how to do that either. Can you show me how I would do that with my above code?

Comment: @trevoray did you think of searching on google an example?

Comment: @Mederic, yes I googled before I came here. I saw examples of using very long JSOn scripts but that seems over kill when I'm only ever going to have these exact parameters and will only be using it for this single textbox entry.

Comment: did you google "vb.net regex matches"

Comment: @Mederic yes I googled that as well. The problem is I can't figure out from the goolgle search results how to implement your example into my code. If i was more proficient in RegEx I wouldn't be here asking for help.

Comment: @trevoray https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-matches-vbnet copy paste and replace by the regex i gave you

Comment: @mederic tks! that worked

Comment: If that code works for you, you should be able to submit it as an answer to your own question.  You should post it as an actual answer, not in the question-body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regex Approach:

A cleaner approach to the Regex using groups

First:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Then:

```
'Our regex
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("(?<start>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*(?<end>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})")
'Match from textbox content
Dim match As Match = regex.Match(TextBox1.Text)
'If match is success
If match.Success Then
    'Print start group
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups("start").Value)
    'Print end group
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups("end").Value)
End If
```

Explanation of the Regex:

`(?<start>REGEX)` = Captures a group named `start`

`(?<end>REGEX)` = Captures a group named `end`

`\d` = Matches a digit

`{X}` = Matches for X occurences

`.*` = Makes sure we match **zero** or **one** example so not both groups are named start

Example:

`\d{4}` = Matches 4 digits

### Json Approach

Json approach would be possible but a bit more complex I think to implement as you have a illegal name in your Json String: `end`

But if you wanted to use Json you could import `Newtonsoft.Json`

And have a class as:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property start As String
    Public Property _end As String
End Class
```

And then deserialize like this:

```
Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(TextBox1.Text)
```

However you would need to implement: `DataContract` and `DataMember` 
To handle the word `end`

[DataContract MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Named Capture Groups might make the regex approach look a little nicer, instead of having to loop.  I don't particularly *like* the regex approach to this, but you are right, the "correct" json way is going to be complex because of naming issues in this case.

Comment: @BradleyUffner i'll look into it and update the answer i'm beginner in Regex thanks for the tip

Comment: @BradleyUffner would this be ok then? `(?<start>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*(?<end>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})`

Comment: @BradleyUffner thanks for the tip then i'll edit my answer